# Enable align justified in UILabel with multilines

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilabel

while setting `NSTextAlignmentJustified`

[image: wrong result]

Comment: whats your question ..?

Comment: From the picture above, spacing during the letters in the label is strange...How to align the text left and right correctly?

Comment: Play with the width of your UILabel.

Comment: take maximum height of your label & then use [LabelName SizeToFit];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,I have found the reason for it.Actually,it's the problem caused by \n,\r,\r\n

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest set the height accordindg to text..if you want the label text in multilines with NSTextalignmentJustified use this ...

label.numberOfLines = 0

Make sure label is having enough height accourding  to text.